# write text on each h4 of my html using array of the API

Tags: jquery, html, css, api

```
var DomReady = function(){
var _url = 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/home.json?api-key=b66efec295294cf38e816b25c409a35d';
$.get(_url, function(data){
    console.log(data.results);
    console.log($('h4').length);
    for(var i=0; i < data.results.length; i++){
        console.log(data.results[i].title);
        $('h4').append(data.results[i].title);

    }

})
}
```

`$(document).ready(DomReady);`

```
 <div class='container grid'>
    <div class='card col-2 s-col-6'>
            <img src='Obama.jpg'/>
        <div>
            <h4 class='FontBlack'></h4>
            <p class='pBlack14'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='card col-2 s-col-6'>
            <img src='Obama.jpg'/>
        <div>
            <h4 class='FontBlack'></h4>
            <p class='pBlack14'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hi,

I have a problem with my code, i work with an API of the New York Times and i would like to make a loop for write text on each h4 of my html element.
These elements are in an array and i want to know how can i achieve to put each title of news in each h4 differently.
I try with .append but it doesn't work.
Do you have an Issue ?

Thanks a lot

Sorry for my english, i'm from France :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var items = '',
        data_length = data.results.length;
    for(var i=0; i < data_length; i++){
        items += "<div class='card col-2 s-col-6'>
                  <img src='Obama.jpg'/>
                  <div>
                    <h4 class='FontBlack'>"+ data.results[i].title +"</h4>
                    <p class='pBlack14'>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                  </div>
                 </div>"
    }

    $('.container.grid').append(items);
```

It is a simple variant. If you want do code more clear look to the "jQuery Templates" https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery-tmpl/